# How to make a efficient menu where the user has to input the full option?

Tags: c#, loops, if-statement, switch-statement, user-input

I'm doing a menu screen where the user needs to input exactly one of the options. Currently I'm doing this:

```
static void Start()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Options: " + Environment.NewLine);
        string[] options = { "Option 1", "Option 2", "Option 3" };
        foreach (string value in options)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(value);
        }
        Console.Write("Type the option you want: ");
        string choosen = Console.ReadLine();
        if(choosen == "Option 1")
        {
            Console.WriteLine(Environment.NewLine + "Your choosen option was Option 1" + Environment.NewLine);
            Start();
        }
        else if (choosen == "Option 2")
        {
            Console.WriteLine(Environment.NewLine + "Your choosen option was Option 2" + Environment.NewLine);
            Start();
        }
        else if(choosen == "Option 3")
        {
            Console.WriteLine(Environment.NewLine + "Your choosen option was Option 3" + Environment.NewLine);
            Start();
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine(Environment.NewLine + "Please choose a valid option!" + Environment.NewLine);
            Start();
        }
    }
```

I can tell it's not a very efficient way of doing it but I don't know any other way.

I know I could do it like this:

```
ConsoleKeyInfo key = Console.ReadKey();
        switch (key.Key)
        {
            case ConsoleKey.D1:
                Console.WriteLine(Environment.NewLine + "Your choosen option was Option 1" + Environment.NewLine);
                Start();
                break;
            case ConsoleKey.D2:
                Console.WriteLine(Environment.NewLine + "Your choosen option was Option 2" + Environment.NewLine);
                Start();
                break;
            case ConsoleKey.D3:
                Console.WriteLine(Environment.NewLine + "Your choosen option was Option 3" + Environment.NewLine);
                Start();
                break;
            default:
                Console.WriteLine(Environment.NewLine + "Please choose a valid option!" + Environment.NewLine);
                Start();
                break;
        }
```

But I want the user to write fully one of the the options, like "Option 1" or so. This way the user needs to press a single key.

So, is there a more efficient way of doing this, or for this exact purpose, I can only do the way I've been doing it? I really don't like having a if-else statement for each option I've got.

Comment: Can you provide more context? I'm assuming the program will do different things depending upon the option chosen?

Comment: @SteveJ yes, actually there are another methods with the corresponding option that will return a different thing, but I did this code to simplify it.

Comment: Why don't you combine the two options? Read the option as a string and use a switch on the string

Comment: @AlexandruPupsa that works but in reality I need the options to go to other Methods that sometimes are in other classes to. Steve answer covers that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this...

```
public class Option
{
    public string Description { get; }
    public string Method { get; }

    public Option(string description, string method)
    {
        Description = description;
        Method = method;
    }
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var options = new[]
        {
            new Option("1 to print \"Hello\".", "PrintHello"),
            new Option("2 to print \"World\".", "PrintWorld")
        };

        Console.WriteLine("Please press the number of the desired option:");
        foreach (var option in options)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{option.Description}");
        }

        char key;

        while (true)
        {
            key = Console.ReadKey().KeyChar;
            if (key >= '1' && key <= '0' + options.Length)
            {
                break;
            }
            Console.WriteLine($"{Environment.NewLine}Please choose an option from 1 to {options.Length}");
        }

        Console.WriteLine($"{Environment.NewLine}You selected option {key}");

        var selected = options[key - '1'];

        typeof(Program).GetMethod(selected.Method).Invoke(null, null);

        // This line is just to stop the console window closing
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public static void PrintHello()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello");
    }

    public static void PrintWorld()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("World");
    }
}
```

Obviously this will only work for up to 9 options. Also, it would need to be a bit different if the methods you want to call aren't static. If this is the case, let me know and I can provide a further example.

Comment: Can you please explain to me what exactly the line      typeof(Program).GetMethod(selected.Method).Invoke(null, null);     does?

Comment: Sure. In the Options class, the property Method contains the name of the method you want to run. typeof gets the type of the class "Program". Once you have that, you can use reflection to find information about the class and dynamically invoke (run) methods.

Comment: You're welcome. I've simplified the example, the Key property on the Option class was redundant.